# How to structure backend to minimize number of axios calls required

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I am working on an application with Laravel and VueJs. In this application, a person can create an event and can create participants. Participants have a foreign key called event_id. After the event and the participants are created I need to pair people's names together.

Right now in my form method in the vuejs component, this is how my code is structured:

```
submitForm() {
    //creates events
    axios.post('/api/event/store', this.form)
        .then(response => {
             //creates participants
             axios.post('/api/participant/massStore', {
                participants: this.participantsForm,
                event_id: response.data.id
              }).then(response => {

                  //pairs participants
                  axios.post('/api/event/pairParticipants');
              })
         });
}
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this in order to not have to have as many axios post calls? Right now I create the event in the EventController, create the participants in the ParticipantController, and then pair the participants in the EventController. The pairing must be done after all the participants have been created.

Thank you!

Comment: Submit all of your information to a single end point, then chain execution; insert first information, insert second, then pair/link them. This is essentially what you're already doing, but the triggers are broken up into `AJAX` calls when they probably don't need to be.

Comment: Could you explain this process a little more? Would love to explore it. Could you give me an example on how to do what you are suggesting?

Comment: Create a single endpoint like `/event/storeAndMassPair` (or similar), define the route and controller that will handle that end point (something like `EventController@postStoreAndMassPair`), then take all the code from the 3 end points your currently have and mash them into that method. Then, make sure you post all the correct information (`this.form` and `this.participantsForm`), and have your code use the input as necessary. Anywhere you'd return a `json` response, move to the next set of logic and only return when everything is done. It's a bit broad of a concept, so that's the best from me

Comment: Gotcha. Is this not bad practice though? I would be meshing all of the logic that could be seperated into controllers? Thanks so much!

Comment: I'd rather keep them separate like you have now. Imagine in the future you need to pair participants that already exist on an event. If you cram everything together you'll have 1 of two things 1) you can't do this operation anymore 2) you have duplicated code so pairing can be done on its own. IMO you're better off to leave it.
You can clean that js up a bit with async await if that's what's bothering you though.

Comment: If you don't want to "mash it all together", you can have the Controller methods call other Controller methods, but I actually think that's worse practice than the other approach I suggested. But again, that's open to opinion. At this point, it might be better to open this question again on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/; that's the place for asking for alternate approaches/best practices/etc regarding existing functional code.

Answer (score 0):

Minimizing the number of AJAX calls with axios really depends on your own data needs. You can also echo out JSON into the page with view blades for Javascript to pick up.

If you want to limit the number of routes to create then take a look at solutions like [Graph QL and this library](https://github.com/nuwave/lighthouse).